# too many sockets in Bound state

Tags: java, sockets

In one of our customer system we are facing Too many open files error, Currently the FD limit is set to max and this is happening once in a week.

After seeing lsof and netstat o/p, i was able to see too many Sockets were in BOUND state(20K). As i understand this state is a transient state, I am not able to find where its actually leaking. When i see in the heapDump for the one of the bounded socket i see the following GC references

```
>java.net.InetSocketAddress
 >> sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl
  >>>sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor
   >>>>java.net.SocksSocketImpl
    >>>>>java.lang.ref.Finalizer
```

I am not getting any clue how resolve this. i am in need of expert opinion on the same?

Answer (score 3):

To ensure a socket is close()d it is closed from the Finalizer thread.

The Finalizer thread is single threaded and if this is running slow (e.g. because you haven't closed your connections correctly) you can be creating sockets faster than you are cleaning them up.

The first thing to check is to take a stack dump and see what the finalizer thread is usually waiting for. Secondly check you *always* close your socket connections when you are finished with them. The sockets will still be added to the Finalizer queue, but they won't take any time to check they are already closed.

Answer (score 1):

You are leaking sockets badly. Somewhere you are not closing them in a finally block when you should. I would guess from the BOUND state that somewhere you are calling new Socket(), then calling connect(), and if it fails you aren't closing the a socket, but there could be many other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the Hints, We were able to dig out the issue. . Actually nio was throwing an unresovedAddress exception, in that case soket resources were not cleaned up but when IOException was raised every resources were cleaned up and released, now we just handled UnresolvedAddressException. . Fix was simple but took time to boil down to issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Hints, We were able to dig out the issue. . Actually nio was throwing an unresovedAddress exception, in that case soket resources were not cleaned up but when IOException was raised every resources were cleaned up and released, now we just handled UnresolvedAddressException. . Fix was simple but took time to boil down to issue :)